# making instance of class in c#

Tags: c#, class, object

In this code

```
using System;
namespace Hello
{
    class TestEmployee
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Employee employee = new Employee();
            employee.salary = 1000;
            employee.bonus = 100;
            employee.CacalculateTotalPay();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
    class Employee
    {
        public double salary;
        public double bonus;
        public void CacalculateTotalPay()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(salary + bonus);
        }
    }
}
```

Why should we make a instance of a class with the `new` keyword when we already declared the employee variables type with `Employee` class?

I didn't tried anything.

Comment: "why we should make instance of a class with new" - because that's how you create an instance of a class. Just declaring the variable doesn't create an instance of a class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you declare a variable for a class without the `new` operator any assignment, like this:

```
Employee employee;
```

you don't actually have an instance of the class yet. There is no Employee object here. What you have is a variable with the *potential* to refer to a class instance. Initially there isn't anything there; only the potential... it is a null reference. Therefore we might also create a `new` instance of the type and assign that new instance to our variable:

```
Employee employee = new Employee();
```

You could avoid this by making the `Employee` type `static`. Then, instead of declaring a variable at all you would refer to its members via the type name (ie `Employee.salary`). However, that's limiting. If you refer to the members via type name you would have no way to distinguish one employee from another, and you likely expect to have many more than just the one employee.

Therefore we do not use `static` and instead create new instances so that each instance can represent a different employee.

This can be confusing for new programmers, because the first exposure to code is often via a class with a static `Main()` method, where you did not need to create an instance, and with primitive types like `int` and `string` that have support in the language so you don't need to use the `new` operator. It may be some time before you progress far enough to need to worry about object instances. But rest assured, over time instances are the norm, and `static` and `struct` will be less common.

Finally, it is important to come to terms with the difference between object instances, references, variables, and types (classes/structs). Those are four different kinds of thing, and it is difficult to write effective code without understanding how they relate to each other.